# logback-spring.xml how I can archive to gz if <prudent>true</prudent>

Tags: spring, logging, configuration, gzip, logback

how I can archive to gz if `<prudent>true</prudent>`? my logging configuration in logback-spring.xml and I can't switch off prudent. How I need change configuration? May be I need make new appender?

```
`<appender name="logstash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <prudent>true</prudent>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${loggingMaxHistory:2}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>`
 . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

in logback-spring.xml you can't use correct way, because new appender will write their log in general log file. you will have double lines in log. I chose another way. write bash script (two variants) and place it at folder /etc/cron.daily/
1 variant - script archiving files after n-day create/change

```
mkdir -p /var/log/archive/ ;
find /var/log/*.log  -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -exec gzip "{}" \;
mv /var/log/hi1/*.gz /var/log/archive/ ;
```

2 variant - script archiving files after n-day create by date from filename (xxx-yyyymmdd.log)

```
#!/bin/bash
logFolder='/logs/'
archFolder=$logFolder'archive/'
mkdir -p $archFolder ;
todayDate="$(date +%Y%m%d)"
todayMon=${todayDate:4:2}
todayDay=${todayDate:6:2}
todayYear=${todayDate:0:4}
lastMon=$(($todayMon-1))
#days after present not archived
backlog=3

if (( $lastMon>0 )); then
  last=$(echo $(cal ${lastMon} ${todayYear}) | awk '{print $NF}')
else
  last=31
fi

for i in $logFolder*.log; do
  logDate=$(basename "$i" ".log" | egrep -o  '[0-9]'| xargs)
  logDate2=$(echo "$logDate" | sed 's/ //g')
  logDiffDate=$((todayDate - logDate2))
  logmin=(100-$last)
  logmax1=$((100+$backlog))
  logmax=($logmax1-$last)
  logone=$(($backlog+1))
  
  if (($logDiffDate>$logone)); then
    if (($logmin>$logDiffDate)); then
      gzip $i
    fi
    if (($logmax<$logDiffDate)); then
      gzip $i
    fi
  fi
done
mv $logFolder*.gz $archFolder ;
```

first variant shorter second smarter